# How would I do a GET and parameters requests in ncat using udp?

Tags: networking, http, udp, netcat

I'm trying to learn the difference between http and udp. 
So how would I request via udp: 
udp://server/path_name?param1=value1&param2=value2

Theoretically is that kind of thing possible or am I talking nonsense ?

Answer (score 0):

> Theoretically is that kind of thing possible or am I talking nonsense ?

Unfortunately the latter is the case.
UDP and TCP are both transport layer protocols, while HTTP is an application layer protocol on top of TCP. URL's like you give in your question are not defined with plain UDP or TCP but would need to have some application layer protocol to interpret the data in the URL in a meaningful way.